# This problem occurs to me whenever I try to add a new library in the Android Studio gradle file in the Java language

Tags: java, android, gradle, navigation, classpath

The project is working perfectly, but when I added this library, the problems started to disappear

`implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1'`

this message showed after build my pro

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

and
`Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1.`

this is my gradle.build  module file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'greenline.fpotwotw.poeter'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "greenline.fpotwotw.poeter"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3'
    //implementation 'com.androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation  'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker:2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8"

    implementation  "com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:balloon:1.2.9"
    implementation "com.hbb20:ccp:2.6.0"


    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'

    implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1'

    //implementation "com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.3.2"

    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
}
```

and project path  gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

and gradle.setting

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    }
}
rootProject.name = "Poeter"
include ':app'
```

Can someone with experience help us, thank you very much.